# The Java ClassLoader Security Model

Tags: java, security, jvm, classloader

I'm trying to understand the security model used when the JVM is asked to load classes.

From the JVM specification on Sandboxing, I'm given to believe that a standard JVM implementation should maintain at least one other `ClassLoader`, independent of the `primordial ClassLoader`. This is used to load the application class files (from a provided classpath for example).

If the class is requested from the `ClassLoader` that is not in it's namespace, `java/lang/String` for example, then it forwards the request to the primordial `ClassLoader`, which attempts to load the class from the Java API, if its not there then it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Am I right in thinking that the primordial `ClassLoader` only loads classes from the Java API namespace, and all other classes are loaded via a separate `ClassLoader` implementation?

And that this makes the loading of classes more secure because it means that a malicious class cannot masquerade as a member of the Java API (lets say `java/lang/Virus`) because this is a protected namespace, and cannot be used in the current `ClassLoader`?

But is there anything to prevent the Classes of the Java API being replaced by malicious classes, or would that be detected during `class` verification?

Comment: Basically correct.  The "primordial" ClassLoader is known as the "boot ClassLoader" and loads classes from the "boot classpath".  The protection afforded by this is reasonably "strong" so long as the "security officer" controls the JVM invocation (eg, command line) where the boot classpath is specified.

Comment: (A few JVMs have additional security on the boot classpath, requiring that the JARs there have a privileged attribute.)

Comment: @HotLicks The `boot classpath` being where the Java runtime is located?

Comment: The boot classpath being the default classpath for loading the JDK.  Overridden with the -Xbootclasspath directive on the `java` command.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for your help. Is there any anything to stop malicious code being placed on the boot classpath to replace JDK classes? As per the last line of my question.

Comment: There's nothing in Java (on most systems) that can protect against someone modifying the files on your system outside of Java, if that's what you mean.  That's up to your standard system protection features.  Inside Java, if you run untrusted code directly (rather than "sandboxing" it with the proper SecurityManager then you're also at risk, of course.  But inside Java, with a proper SecurityManager in place, there's no hazard (that I know of) in running untrusted code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For historical reasons the names used for class loaders are a little peculiar. The boot class loader loads the systems classes. The system class loader, by default, loads classes from the class path not the system classes. The system classes are in jre/lib (mostly in rt.jar), endorsed directories and anywhere added through `-Xbootclasspath`.

On the Sun/Oracle JRE, rt.jar contains classes with packages starting with java., javax., sun., com.sun., org.omg, org.w3c and org.xml.

Untrusted code (including configuration) should not be able to add to the system classes. Some packages name prefixed may be restricted through a security property. The java. prefix is specially protected against for non-technical reasons.

Generally a class loader will delegate to its parent before defining a new class, preventing any classes from an ancestor loader from being replaced. Java EE recommends (even though Java SE bans) having some class loaders prefer their own classes, typically to use a more up to date API or a different implementation. This allows shadowing of classes, but only as seen through that loader (and its children). All other classes continue to link to the original.

Comment: You sound like the JVM Spec. `For historical reasons` is their excuse for everything ;)